# vue2: can not find a proper way to initialize component data by ajax

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component whose data is initialized by ajax. I know vue.js has provide several lifecycle hooks: [Lifecycle-Diagram](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram). But for ajax to initialize the data, which hook(beforeCreate, create, mounted, etc) is the best place to do it:

```
hook_name: function() {
    ajaxCall(function(data) {
        me.data = data;
    });
}
```

Currently, i do it in `mounted`, making it to re-render the component. But i think we should get the data before the first render. Can someone figure out the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to initialize your component with data you receive from a `request`, `created()` would be the most appropriate hook to use **but** it is a `request`, it **might not resolve** by the end of `created` or even `mounted()` (when even your DOM is ready to show content!).

So do have your component initialized with empty data like:

```
data () {
  return {
    listOfItems: [],
    someKindOfConfig: {},
    orSomeSpecialValue: null
  }
}
```

and assign the actual values when you receive them in your `created` hook as these empty `data` properties would be available at that point of time, like:

```
created () {
  someAPICall()
    .then(data => {
       this.listOfItems = data.listOfItems
    })
    /**
    *  Notice the use of arrow functions, without those [this] would
    *  not have the context of the component.
    */
}
```

It seems like you aren't using (or aren't planning to use) [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html) but I'd highly recommend you to use it for for managing your data in stores. If you use `vuex` you can have `actions` which can make these api calls and by using simple `getters` in your component you would have access to the values returned by the `request`.